# Cannot run `apt update` "At least one invalid signature was encountered"

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I am not able to `sudo apt-get` update successfully. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

I have looked at other question about this issue but gets another problem when I follow the solution.

Here it is:

```
kenneth@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for kenneth: 
Get:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]    
Get:3 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB]   
Get:4 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [92.2 kB] 
Ign:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Fetched 529 kB in 0s (908 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried:

```
$ sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp
```

but when I do

```
$ sudo apt update
```

again, I get the same invalid signature errors.

Comment: You are trying to move a directory named 'lists' on top of another directory named 'lists', mv doesn't allow that. Either rename the one in /tmp or mv to another location, if indeed that's *really* what you want to do.

Comment: What will you recommend me to do?

Comment: @Zanna Actually if the target directory isn't empty (i.e. you have the same named target directory which contains files) mv will not rename the source. But your warning remains apposite! I can't edit my comment to clarify.

Comment: your real problem looks like this one? or maybe the linked post [Apt encounters errors with bad GPG keys](//askubuntu.com/q/198371)

Comment: Maybe I am stupid but nothing really works.

Comment: Can it have something to do with Disable all PPA repositories. I must only have official Ubuntu repositories active?

Comment: Someone who have a suggestion?

Comment: Check if you have free space on `/`.